# Complex Exponential Function Integration

Tags: integration, exponential-function, complex-integration

I am looking for a compact form solution for this integral:

$$\psi (\nu) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{i \nu x}}{(1+a\,x)^2} dx,$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, and $a>0$ is a constant and $\nu$ is Real . I searched the table of integrals book but didn't find what I am looking for. Does this mean that I need to find this integration numerically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $\nu$ ?

Comment: You'll most likely want to integrate by parts

Comment: I feel like Feynman’s trick might be useful here along with integration by parts.

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC The result will be a function of v.

Comment: @FrankW. What is Feynman's trick?

Comment: I tried integration by parts, but it leads to nowhere.

Comment: @BlackMath Differentiation under the integral sign. You can set $I$ equal to the integral in your question, try intregration by parts, and try to represent the remaining integral in terms of $I’$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration by parts using 
 $$u={{e}^{i\nu x}}and\ dv=\frac{1}{{{\left( 1+ax \right)}^{2}}}$$   yields:

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{e}^{i\nu x}}}{{{\left( 1+ax \right)}^{2}}}dx}=\left. \frac{-{{e}^{i\nu x}}}{a\left( 1+ax \right)} \right|_{0}^{\infty }+\frac{i\nu }{a}\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{e}^{i\nu x}}}{\left( 1+ax \right)}dx}=\frac{-1}{a}+\frac{i\nu }{a}\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{e}^{i\nu x}}}{\left( 1+ax \right)}dx}$$

Now use  $${{e}^{i\nu x}}=\ \cos \left( \nu x \right)+i\sin \left( \nu x \right)$$

$$I=\frac{-1}{a}+\frac{i\nu }{a}\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{\cos \left( \nu x \right)}{\left( 1+ax \right)}dx}-\frac{\nu }{a}\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{\sin \left( \nu x \right)}{\left( 1+ax \right)}dx}\ =\frac{-1}{a}+\frac{i\nu }{a}{{I}_{1}}-\frac{1}{a}{{I}_{2}}$$

Where these two integrals can be found in terms of [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) and [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).

Comment: After using your approach, I reach to the formula $\psi(t)=1+itE_1(-it)$ for $a=1$, and where $E_1$ is the exponential integral function. However, when I tried to find the inverse Fourier transform of $\psi(t)$ numerically using Mathematica, it didn't give me what it is supposed to give me, which is $1/(1+x)^2$. Why?

Comment: $\psi \left( \nu  \right)$ is not the is not the fourier transform of $\frac{1}{{{\left( 1+ax \right)}^{2}}}$

Comment: Why not? It is the characteristic function, and the books I read state that it is the Fourier transform of the PDF, and thus the PDF can be found by the inverse Fourier Transform. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not familiar with "characteristic functions", but you can use Mathematica to find the fourier transform of $\psi \left( \nu  \right)$ and evaluate the integral in question, you will find the  two results different.

Comment: I have searched the internet for  characteristic function and its relationship with fourier transform and it is indeed as you said, but notice that the rage of integration for both of them is from -infinity to infinity while the integral in question is from zero to infinity, i think this what you are missing.

Comment: This is only because the range of the x random variable in my case is from 0 to infinity. This doesn't mean that this is no longer a Fourier transform of the PDF. This implies that the inverse Fourier transform of the characteristic function should give the PDF, which doesn't happen for some reason I cannot pinpoint!!

Comment: Maybe you have an error in your calculations, check it again??

Comment: OK, when I did it manually, I got the PDF correctly. So, the derivation is correct. But Mathematica and MATLAB failed to evaluate it using the inverse Fourier transform, even at specific points. This is problematic, because this is the PDF of one random variable. What I wish to find is the PDF of the summation of such random variables, which requires numerical evaluation. It is not possible to do it manually.

Comment: Why did you assume that $$\nu = -\frac{1}{1+x}$$ and not $$1-\frac{1}{1+x}$$ In my analysis $1/(1+x)^2$ is the PDF and $1-1/(1+x)$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$. So, it makes more sense use $$\nu = 1-\frac{1}{1+x}$$ in which case we are encountered with the problem of evaluating complex exponential at $\infty$!! How to solve it in this case?